# Don't understand why I am getting an unresolved external symbol?

Tags: c++

I don't understand why I am getting an unresolved external symbol in this specific example.

I have a Rectangle struct defined in a header file.

I have a Level class which has a pointer to a Player class as the Level creates a new player.

I my Player class, the constructor takes in a pointer to it's current level.

So since my Level includes `Player.h` I forward declare Level in my Player class to prevent a circular reference.

However, when I try and add a Rectangle member variable to my Player class - I get the unresolved external symbol error, but I can't see why - since the Player class includes the header - and the definition is in the header. It works fine in my Level class.

Also - if I change the member variable to a pointer it links fine.

Can someone explain to me why this is the case and how I can fix the issue?

```
// Rectangle.h

#pragma once

namespace Test
{
    struct Rectangle
    {
    public:
        Rectangle();

        Rectangle(
            int x,
            int y,
            int width,
            int height) :
            X(x),
            Y(y),
            Width(width),
            Height(height)
        {
        }

        int X;
        int Y;
        int Width;
        int Height;
    };
}

// Level.h

#pragma once

#include "Player.h"
#include <memory>

namespace Test
{
    class Level
    {
    public:
        Level()
        {
            _player.reset(new Player(this));
        };
    private:
        std::unique_ptr<Player> _player;
    };
}

// Player.h

#pragma once

#include "Rectangle.h"

namespace Test
{
    class Level;

    class Player
    {
    public:
        Player(
            Level* currentLevel) :
            _currentLevel(currentLevel)
        {
        }
    private:
        Level* _currentLevel;

        // This line causes the issue
        Rectangle _localBounds;
    };
}
```

Comment: Show the error you get? You never define the default constructor of Rectangle, AFAICS.

Comment: OH MY GOD. Guys. Thank you. How did I miss that. Someone create a reply and I'll mark it accepted. I am such a doofus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to add braces on your Rectangle constructor. Make it like this:

```
Rectangle() {}
```

So the problem is you have the definition but not the implementation. You can indeed declare a function without braces but it is like you make a promise to the compiler that you are going to add the function's body somewhere else. That's why separating classes to .hpp and .cpp files works.

**Note**: Retired Ninja gave the answer first in a comment below the post.